# Combine WITH statement with UNION

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query, and i want the output in
a single row with the delimeter  **|**  separating my data :

```
WITH X AS (
    SELECT 'WLT_CUSTOMER' AS TABLE_NAME_STAGING_AREA, 
        COUNT(*) as TOTAL_WLT_CUSTOMERS 
    FROM WLT_CUSTOMER 
    where WLT_DATE = (SELECT SCHEDULED_DATE FROM BANK_PARAMETERS)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CUSTOMER' AS TABLE_NAME_PRODUCTION_DATABASE,
        COUNT(*) as TOTAL_CUSTOMERS 
    FROM CUSTOMER 
    where CUST_ID <> 0
)
SELECT X.TABLE_NAME_STAGING_AREA
        || '|'
        || X.TOTAL_WLT_CUSTOMERS 
        || '|'
        || X.TABLE_NAME_PRODUCTION_DATABASE
        || '|'
        || X.TOTAL_CUSTOMERS 
FROM X
```

It gives me error ORA-00904: "X"."TOTAL_CUSTOMERS": invalid identifier .

An expected output should be something like this :
WLT_CUSTOMER | 10 | CUSTOMER | 30

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve

Comment: i want an output in only one row , something like this :
WLT_CUSTOMER | 10 | CUSTOMER | 30

Comment: no the subquery works fine by itself

Comment: The CTE returns 2 columns, TABLE_NAME_STAGING_AREA and TOTAL_WLT_CUSTOMERS (named in the UNION's first select). Your select uses 4 columns.

Comment: You're right. Do you have any idea how am i gonna achieve the output i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select 'WLT_CUSTOMER'||'|'||(
    select COUNT(*) as TOTAL_WLT_CUSTOMERS 
    FROM WLT_CUSTOMER 
    where WLT_DATE = (SELECT SCHEDULED_DATE FROM BANK_PARAMETERS))
    ||'|'||'CUSTOMER'||'|'||
    (select  COUNT(*) as TOTAL_CUSTOMERS 
    FROM CUSTOMER 
    where CUST_ID <> 0) from dual;
```

Comment: This worked fine (i only had to add my delimeter) . Thanks a lot!